# resizing an original image result in a fluo green image

Tags: imageresizer

normal image: https://www.4office.be/images/products/7093442.jpg
resized : https://www.4office.be/images/products/7093442.jpg?w=360&h=360

probably corrupt original?
how to correct?

tx
Luc

Comment: Similar issue, deleted: [Image resizer, when resizing a particular image converts the image green. All other images are resizing fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66392934/image-resizer-when-resizing-a-particular-image-converts-the-image-green-all-ot)

Comment: a deleted issue doesn't help...

Comment: Associating the two posts might attract more attention to your question. To me, it's helpful to know someone else has experienced a similar issue, despite the post's removal.